# Web Wallet Creation with PHP and bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, address, e-wallet

How would one start creating a web wallet?  What I have so far:

1. Generate an address per user of the wallet using bitcoind

   - How can I secure the private key?
2. Tell user deposit address using bitcoind and php
3. Get balance of address after a deposit using more php? (what RPC call must I use?)
4. Here's where I am stuck - How can I allow the user to send to somewhere else?

Thank you

Comment: as I posted as a guest I cannot add a comment to your answer. As for securing private keys, all I need to do is keep them offline, correct? (Not on an internet-connected database)

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using sxtools/libbitcoin or maybe just the blockchain.info API. You can make private keys using a vanitygen if you want to make addresses without using bitcoind and perhaps (if you are skilled enough) create raw transactions and push them straight to blockchain or chain sites or even a public bitcoind.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done the first 3 this should have been pretty easy. All you need to do is use sendfrom as listed on the bitcoin rpc api at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list. The information for sendfrom is pretty self explanatory. Your first question on how to secure a private key is pretty broad you should learn more about bitcoin if you are still confused by this as it seems you want to offer this service to others.